# How do you describe the person an adulterer had his/her affair with?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm wondering if there's a proper term to describe the partner with whom someone cheats.

I am not married. I had an affair with Caitlin who is married (it was one time and it didn't mean anything). Caitlin is an adulterer/adulteress but what would that make me?

"I don't think it's fair for me to be forever branded a ____."

Comment: Weren't you the correspondent?

Comment: You just had extramarital sex (with a married woman). Note that having sex on a single occasion might be described as a "one-night stand" (especially if you had little or no social interaction before and/or after "doing the deed"), but it would never be called "having an affair" ("affairs" are more substantial affairs! :).

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I don't think it means anything to be "the correspondent" unless you're being *cited* as such in a divorce action (the correspondent being the person that the person you're suing for divorce against had sex with, and *that's* the reason for the divorce in the first place)..

Comment: Maybe a poacher. Or, a homewrecker. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/homewrecker

Comment: The other person

Comment: The question title asks about how to describe you, but the question body asks about how to describe your action. There is a mismatch there.

Comment: I agree with @DjinTonic; If the three people were in a room, you'd identify them as the husband, the cheating wife and the *other guy*

Comment: The lover is what that would make you. Did you ever see the movie: The Cook, the Thief, His Wife & Her Lover lover is usually more than once.

Comment: The term 'branded' implies that you are looking for a term that incorporates a negative judgment into its meaning, rather than an evaluatively neutral one. Was that your intention? (That affects whether *homewrecker* may be a good answer.)

Comment: The duplicate question is about *significant others*, who would not necessarily be married. In this question, one party is married. *Adultery* is "Voluntary sexual intercourse between a married person and another who is not his or her spouse..." (*OED*)

Answer (score 2):

> "I don't think it's fair for me to be forever branded **the other
> man/woman**."

More formally:

> The person an adulterer has an affair with is the **third party**.

**other man** (n.)

> A man with whom a married woman has an affair —usually used with *the*
>
> *E.G. Marshall plays a man who, believing himself cuckolded, plants a bomb in his own basement to destroy the Mrs. and **the other man.*** —
> Mike Flaherty [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other%20man#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20other%20man,Mike%20Flaherty)

> The lover of a married woman or female partner. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/other_man)

**other woman** (n.)

> A woman with whom a married man has an affair —usually used with *the*
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other%20woman)

> The female lover of a married or similarly attached person.
>
> *Her husband left the matrimonial home to live with **the other woman**.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/other_woman)

**third party** (n.)

> A person or group besides the two primarily involved in a situation,
> especially a dispute.
>
> *the involvement of a third party as an independent valuer*
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/third_party)

---

> "Adultery: What About **the Other Woman (or Man)**?" Looking at the
> ethics of adultery from the other side... [psychologytoday.com](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/maybe-its-just-me/201004/adultery-what-about-the-other-woman-or-man)

> Question
>
> Can I sue **the other woman** for destroying my marriage?
>
> Answer:
>
> This is a very common question, but a pretty uncommon scenario.
> Depending on where you live, you may be able to file suit against **the
> other woman (or man)** through one of two types of civil tort claims – "criminal conversation" or "alienation of affection."
> [Lina Guillen; "Can I sue the other woman for destroying my marriage?", divorcenet](https://www.divorcenet.com/resources/can-i-sue-other-woman-destroying-my-marriage.html)

> Whilst some people call a close friendship between a married man and a
> female more than questionable, others define "being unfaithful" only
> as having actual sexual intercourse with a **third party**. [Petra Falk; *Being **the Other Woman**: the Complete Hanbook for the
> Woman in Love with a Married Man*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Being_the_Other_Woman/UXhGAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22third%20party%22) (2009)

> In general, society looks at **the other man or other woman** as
> being the responsible party in an affair. It’s understandable that
> they become the target for the rage and anger the deceived spouse
> feels. [Cathy Meyer; "4 Tips For Dealing With **The Other Man or Other Woman**",
> liveabout.com](https://www.liveabout.com/tips-for-dealing-with-the-other-man-or-other-woman-1103288)

---

> It is generally recommended against naming the **third party** – it
> can greatly raise tensions, as well as costs and timescales as there
> are more parties in the proceedings. It has been far more usual
> practice for Petitioners to refer to adultery being committed with an
> unnamed man or woman. [Wedlake Bell; "Naming the **third party** in an
> adultery application for divorce"](https://wedlakebell.com/naming-third-party-adultery-application-divorce/)

> How Do We Define Adultery?
>
> ... We might start by saying that what is called for are two
> relations, that between a man and a woman who are married to each
> other, and that between one of these two and a **third party**, who
> might be married, or single. [Edward Gallafent; *Adultery and the
> Female Star*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Adultery_and_the_Female_Star/Q_lcDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=who%20is%20the%20third%20party%20in%20adultery&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> For instance, Gn 38:24 defines a betrothed woman's sexual intercourse
> with a **third party** as adultery deserving the death penalty (see also
> Dt 22:23). [A. Abasili; *The Understanding of Adultery in the Hebrew
> Bible*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Understanding_of_Adultery_in_the_Heb/0nFsDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=who%20is%20the%20third%20party%20in%20adultery&pg=PT217&printsec=frontcover) (2016)

> Respondents will often give acceptable evidence anyway, and this is
> especially so if by giving the confession the respondent is able to
> keep the name of the  **third party** involved out of the suit, as is
> now the norm.... [Frances Burton; *Family Law*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Family_Law/53meQVLypOIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=who%20is%20the%20third%20party%20in%20adultery&pg=PA80&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> It's also extremely unfair to the **third party** involved in the
> affair who oftentimes gets hurt.  [E. Guevara; *Unveiling and
> Conquering Adultery*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Unveiling_and_Conquering_Adultery/uYEuEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=who%20is%20the%20third%20party%20in%20adultery&pg=PT27&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> If the offending spouse is believed to have had an opportunity to
> cheat, and if s/he seemed to be intimate with or fond of a **third
> party**, the courts could consider this as adultery.... [S. Sahni and
> G. Jain; *Internet Infidelity*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Internet_Infidelity/y-xIDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=who%20is%20the%20third%20party%20in%20adultery&pg=PA162&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

Comment: Doesn't the legalese "third party" refer to any wrangle, conflict, misdemeanor, offense or crime committed where the three persons responsible are known. Without context it does not conjure up the lover/sex partner of an unfaithful spouse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA After finding definitions of "other man/woman", I'm putting that answer first. Yes, you need the context of an affair to know what "the third party" refers. to.

Answer (score 0):

Homewrecker is pretty good. Mistress works, but only for a woman, unfortunately. You’re looking for a word for a male mistress. Gigolo or hustler if money was exchanged. Whore can be used in a strong derogative sense quite effectively for either gender. Good luck!

Comment: *Mistress* is much narrower concept, not only because it is limited to women, but also because it can be used only for long-term extramarital partners; an extramarital partner to an one-night stand would not be called a mistress. The term *gigolo* does not imply anything about the marital status of the gigolo's partners; in fact, they are more likely to be unmarried.

Answer (score -1):

Adultery will do.

Here's the definition:

> sex between someone who is married and someone who is not their wife or husband. — [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/adultery)

As it is "between", for both who committed such behaviors, it's called "adultery".

Those who commit adultery are [adulterers](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/adulterer).